# Call API with Javascript that includes Header and includes Token Space API Key

Tags: javascript

I have a challenge where I am building a webpage with html and javascript to have the user input the workpaper ID and then an output populates for the user.  Bonus points if the data retrieved from the json output can be used in calculations.

Below is what I have so far:

[image]

Ideally the user would input their workpaper (ie:SWHC052); there would be another input for the version (ie: 02)

The submit button would populate the data retrieved from the filters the user enters.  Some information:

[image]

example would be "Token 12345b73a0b6378bcfbb4ddb1f9e86f5b4762676" (FAKE)

There has to be a space between the word "Token" and the API Key

Below is the API URL:

Example:
https://www.caetrm.com/api/v1/measures/SWHC020/01/permutations?limit=10&offset=10

Ideally if the user inputted the workpaper as SWHC052
And if the user inputted the version as 02

[https://www.caetrm.com/api/v1/measures/{workpaper](https://www.caetrm.com/api/v1/measures/%7Bworkpaper) from user input}/{version from user input}/permutations?limit=10&offset=10

Then I should receive the data from that call

As a bonus only, it would be great once the data is retrieved to format as a table for the user as well as parse and calculate depending on values retrieved.

Thank you so much for any assistance!